# Does query from contacts provider will block ui thread?

Tags: android

I am writing a call history app. But when i does loading image to listview asynchronously, the scrolling of listview appears quit lag. I have put all the time consuming job to the worker thread and using `ConcurrentHashMap` to ensure the worker thread won't block the ui thread.
But when i loading image from database, the ui thread appear a little lag. To get a image, i query database for a few times and almost cause 1 second. But because it is done in worker thread so i guess it won't cause lag.

But after i debugging using `ddms` and improve the query statement, the lag disappears. But i still can't figure out why. Does query from contentprovider will block the main thread?

**edit**
here is the query code which make the scrolling lag. And the database saves 70000 contacts, so the querying takes quit a long time.

```
public static long loadRawContactId(Context context, long callId) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver(); 
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[] {Calls.NUMBER, Calls.GS_ACCOUNT},
            Calls._ID + " = ?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(callId)},
            null);
    String number = "";
    int account = 0;
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.NUMBER));
            account = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.GS_ACCOUNT));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    Cursor c = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[]{Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID},
            Phone.NUMBER + " = ? AND " + Phone.GS_ACCOUNT + " = ?",
            new String[] {number, String.valueOf(account)},
            null);

    long contactId = 0;
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            contactId = c.getLong(0);
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return contactId;
}
```

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: @Int3ὰ Yes. I found you didn't need to write a custom image loader by youself, because there is quite a lot well written image loader library in github. For example, [ImageLoader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader)